# How to get locator path printed

Tags: java, css, selenium

I'm wondering, how to get the locators path printed?
For example -

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("parent .some_class"))
```

How I can get to the `parent .some_class`?

I've tryied in this way:

```
@FindBy(css = "parent .some_class")
Webelement element;
public Webelement getElement(){ return element; }
System.out.println(getElement);
```

The result:

> [[ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (99c7e4e38147c9f61da0c83c5ef1b992)] -> css selector: parent .some_class]

how to get it to printed\string, so it will be looking as ***parent .some_class***

Use `string.split` is not an option.

Comment: Split is not an option? Why? Would be the easiest way to just split on `"css selector: "`

Comment: Because there is an " ] ", in the end. And I've done it with split( but I'm wondering -  is there any other way to get it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("->(.*)]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(getElement.toString());
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you do by getting the locator path ? If its for reporting purpose then better to go with web-driver even listener. You can refer below steps for the same

**Step 1:** Create an event handler class and implement the `WebDriverEventListener` interface, It will ask for implement all unimplemented method within that class because its an interface and you have to implement its all method.

And there are methods present like -

```
public void beforeFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2)
```

And

```
public void afterFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2)
```

There you can grab what you want.

e.g.

```
@Override
public void afterFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2) {
    System.out.println("Locator info : "+ arg0);
}
```

**Step 2:** To integrate all these stuff you need to use `EventFiringWebDriver` and register the even handler class as below -

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
EventHandler handler = new EventHandler();
eventDriver.register(handler);

eventDriver.get("URL");
eventDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
eventDriver.findElement(By.id("SearchLocationPicker")).click();
eventDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li a[title='Manitoba']")).click();
eventDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li a[title='Flin Flon']")).click();
```

**Output :**

> Locator info : By.id: SearchLocationPicker
>
> Locator info : By.cssSelector: li a[title='Manitoba']
>
> Locator info : By.cssSelector: li a[title='Flin Flon']

For more details please [refer](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/event-listener/).

Comment: Great approach with EventFiringWebDriver